# The C language K&R Exercise 1-8

Tags: c

I sitting right now on K&R The C programming Language . and i have stack on 1 Exercise 1-8 .
The Exercise it self.

**Write a program to replace each tab by three-character sequence >, backspace, -, witch prints as →, and each backspace by the similar ←. This makes tabs and backspaces visible.**

As i understand here that exercise ask me to make pointing arrows in tabs and backspaces. But i cant get how to clip 2 characters together in C
Here is program it self

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()  
{  

int c;

while ((c=getchar()) !=EOF)
{
    if (c == '\t')
        printf(">->->\b");
    if (c == '\b')
        printf("<-<-<-\b");
     if (c !='\t')
         if (c !='\b')
              putchar(c);

}   

  getchar();
}
```

So where is my mistake can you help me here ?

Comment: I'd think the backspace character of the three is intended to erase the tab character, however I'm not quite sure that the backspace can erase another backspace. I find the problem statement ambiguous here. Further, I can't find the exact same problem in K&R 2nd edition.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze: yea i did small mistake in program i should do '>\b-' but my compiler didn't support that kinda code and its showing me only '-' . 2nd Edition of K&R didnt have right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence desired is

```
>\b-
```

Note that this may not work on modern terminal emulators, since most do not support overprinted characters. The original idea was to mimic the old typewriter technique of printing a character, backing the head up by one character, and striking another character over top of the previous one.

If your terminal supports UTF-8, you can substitute the '→' Unicode glyph (U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW), which is encoded in UTF-8 as

```
\xe2\x86\x92
```

Similarly, '←' (U+2190) is

```
\xe2\x86\x90
```

Comment: @user2023937: Like I said, if you're using a modern terminal emulator, it probably won't work. If you're using a terminal emulator that doesn't support UTF-8, then you are unfortunately out of luck. (If you're on Windows, try MinTTY; on Linux, gnome-terminal or Konsole should work; on OS X, the system-provided Terminal.app supports Unicode).

Comment: Im using Visual Studio . Thx will try out those